# How to query Wordpress custom fields from an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problems with `meta_query` in Wordpress. The first example works fine:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post',
    'meta_query' => 
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_field', 
            'value' => '50', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),    
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But what I want to do, as shown below, and in Wordpress documentation, does not work.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post',
    'meta_query' => 
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_field', 
            'value' => array('50','60'), 
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),    
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: "Does not work" tells us nothing. What about it doesn't work? What constitutes a working state? What is it doing that doesn't meet your criteria of a working state?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post',
    'meta_query' => 
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_field', 
            'value' => array(50,60), 
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    ),    
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I'm assuming the `array('50','60')` is meant to be numeric. Try removing the apostrophe and adding the proper type of numeric.

Comment: Hi DaiYoukai, thanks for your help but it still does not work =/